# Powershell Reportwrongprovidertype is not valid?

Tags: powershell, sql-job

```
Write-Host  "Script"

Write-Host "Execute on [$Sever].[$DatabaseN] on $Date"

$Server = "servername"

$DatabaseN =  "name"

$Date = Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd"

      #$Enviroment= "enviroment"

$Enviroment = " eviroment e"

     #$Enviroment = "enviroment"

$SystemProvider = "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem"

$extportfolder = "folder\path"

$Destination = "$SystemProvider ::$exportfolder\$Enviroment"

Write-Host ""

##comment

Write-Host "infotmation"

$Query = Invoke-Sqlcmd -query "select max(id) high from table1 where reason no like '%fail%'" -serverinstance $Server -database $DatabaseN

$Id = $Query.Item("high")

$Output = "$Date - file-$Id.csv"

Write-Host ""

Write-Host "information"

$DataQuery = Invoke-Sqlcmd -query "EXEC [dbo].[outputfile]" -serverinstance $Server -database $DatabaseN

Write-Host ""

Write-Host "information" 

$DataQuery | Export-Csv $Output -notypeinformation -Force

Write-Host ""

Write-Host "information" 

Move-Item -path $Output -Destination $Destination -Force 

Write-Host " Export file = $Id on Server $Server successfully on $Date"
```

Error in `$DataQuery | Export-Csv $Output -notypeinformation -Force`:

path does not exist cannot perform operation because Reportwrongprovidertype is not valid

I dont know why is this error for?

I am trying to Output a csv file to a path using today's date and the last id from the query as the name and inside the file the results of the exec query.

The query runs successfully when using PowerShell ISE but not when running through the sql agent job

Comment: You have a typo: `$extportfolder = "folder\path"` ("folder") but `$Destination = "$SystemProvider ::$exportfoder\$Enviroment"` ("foder"). Since you've made use of these intermediate variables, you could have debugged by printing each of them to see where the error was introduced.

Comment: What are you going through such great lengths to construct a provider-qualified path?

Comment: I fix the typo but still get the same error